# Is there a way in Typescript to simulate the tab key pressed when you press enter on a site's form?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, dom, vuetify.js

I am currently trying to simulate the tab key function when pressing enter on a form in typescript. When the user logs into the site they should be able to navigate a form with the enter key the same way tab navigates the form.

Here is what I have tried that does not work.

```
 enterAsTab(e: any) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log("Enter key was pressed");
      e.keyCode === 9;
      return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `===` is not an assignment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not typescript feature, but Vue

You can add `ref` on each input you want, and just listen `enter` press to change focus on another input.

Example:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    inputsData: {
      inputOne: '',
      inputTwo: '',
      inputThree: '',
      inputFour: '',
    },
  }),
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.inputsData);
    },
    changeFocus(name) {
      if(name) this.$refs[name].focus();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input
      v-model="inputOne"
      ref="input1"
      type="text"
      @keydown.enter.prevent="changeFocus('input2')"
    /><br/>
    <input
      v-model="inputTwo"
      ref="input2"
      type="text"
      @keydown.enter.prevent="changeFocus('input3')"
    /><br/>
    <input
      v-model="inputThree"
      ref="input3"
      type="text"
      @keydown.enter.prevent="changeFocus('input4')"
    /><br/>
    <input
      v-model="inputFour"
      ref="input4"
      type="text"
      @keydown.enter.prevent="changeFocus('input1')"
    /><br/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```